# Loading BPF program into kernel dynamically?

Tags: linux, kernel, ebpf

I'm looking for a way to load a BPF program without rebuilding the kernel.

Comment: It's definitely possible if your kernel supports BPF. What did you try? How did it fail?

Answer (score 2):

Loading programs dynamically, without rebuilding the kernel, is one of the major features of eBPF. eBPF programs are loaded and manipulated using [the `bpf` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html). Most of the time you’d use something like [BCC](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc).

See [the main eBPF site](https://ebpf.io) for detailed guides and tutorials.